# What is this green cap for?

Tags: drywall, pipe

This picture is from a 2nd floor apartment in Colorado. 1st floor is empty, unoccupied retail space. In the apartment's kitchen area there is a enclosed area which is finished with what looks like mold resistant drywall:

[image]

In the box around this area, there is a small, green cap, which I have no idea about what it is for:

[image]

There is no discernible writing on it. I'd guess that it connects to the retail space below, but the space has never been used or rented.

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Likely an empty conduit, perhaps a potential range or wall-oven location, but hard to be sure just from these pictures what it might be intended for. What is your concern? I guess it could also be a capped drain for something like a dishwasher, but that seems less probable given no obvious means of venting and current codes. I can't imagine any reason for it to connect to the space below, rather than some sort of utility.

Comment: I can see a large 2 written on (molded in) it, next to the drywall, and some other stuff I can't make out in this picture, but which you should be able to sort, though it's probably just the brand of the cap.

Comment: Can you peek down the hole, to see if there's some type of pipe or valve attached?

Comment: Agreed - seems unlikely to be linked to downstairs given that it is *inside* the apartment. Will try to make out some of the detail. Seemed odd to be hiding inside the drywall.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ecnerwal. Given the retail space below, and the desire to not disturb that space with future construction needs, it's probably a conduit for power or data cabling.

I'd remove the cap (assuming that it's not glued on) and do some sound testing to find the other end. It's likely in a utility room.